# Unable to position custom styled Tumbler

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols, qtquickextras

I am trying to give a `Tumbler` my own style. I declare the `Tumbler` like this:

```
Tumbler {
    style: MyTumblerStyle {}
    height: UIConstants.smallFontSize * 10
    width: UIConstants.smallFontSize * 3

    TumblerColumn {
        model: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
    }
}
```

where `MyTymblerStyle` is defined like this:

```
TumblerStyle {
    id: root
    visibleItemCount: 5
    background: Rectangle {}
    foreground: Item {}

    frame: Item {}

    highlight: Item {}
    delegate: Item {
        id: delRoot
        implicitHeight: (control.height) / root.visibleItemCount
        Item {
            anchors.fill: parent

            Text {
                text: styleData.value
                font.pixelSize: UIConstants.smallFontSize
                font.family: UIConstants.robotoregular
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                scale: 1.0 + Math.max(0, 1 - Math.abs(styleData.displacement)) * 0.6
                color: styleData.current?UIConstants.color:"black"
                opacity: 1 - Math.abs(styleData.displacement/(root.visibleItemCount-3))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I use it in a `Row` like this:

```
Row {
    MyTumbler {}
    StandardText {
        color: UIConstants.color
        text: "Uhr"
    }
}
```

Now, the result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the `"Uhr"` text center is aligned to the top of the `Tumbler`. Also the `Row` does not seem to recognize the real `width` of the `Tumbler`.

Why? It does work when I do not use `MyTumblerStyle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't your style, it's the `width` assignment.

It helps to break out the `Rectangle`s at a time like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Extras 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 300
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Tumbler {
            id: tumbler
            width: 30

            TumblerColumn {
                model: 25
            }

            Component.onCompleted: print(width, height, implicitWidth, implicitHeight)
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: tumbler.implicitWidth
            height: tumbler.implicitHeight
            color: "transparent"    
            border.color: "blue"

            Text {
                text: "Tumbler implicit size"
                anchors.fill: parent
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: tumbler.width
            height: tumbler.height
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "blue"

            Text {
                text: "The size you gave"
                anchors.fill: parent
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I don't have access to `UIConstants`, so I guess the `width` you set)

[image: tumbler illustration]

The `implicitWidth` of `Tumbler` is [calculated based on the width of each individual `TumblerColumn`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Styles/Base/TumblerStyle.qml#n319). This allows you to set individual widths for columns, something that is necessary for scenarios where some are wider than others, for example:

[image: tumbler date picker]

So, you should also set the `width` of your column, or, preferably, *only* set the `width` of your column, and not the entire `Tumbler`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Extras 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Tumbler {
            id: tumbler

            TumblerColumn {
                model: 25
                width: 30
            }
        }
        Text {
            text: "Uhr"
        }
    }
}
```

This also explains why the `Text` is weirdly positioned; the `Row` sees `30` pixels, but the column still has its original (much wider) width.